# Why does my python program not close

Tags: python, while-loop

I want this code to stop looping the function if the user does not enter yes, y, no or n

```
go = True
def levelOne():
    print "You are in a room"
    print "There is a table, on the table there is a key"
    print "There is a door to the north"
    print "Use the key to open the door and escape?"
    userInput = raw_input()
    str(raw_input).lower()
    if userInput == "y" or userInput == "yes":
        print "Ok"
    elif userInput == "n" or userInput == "no":
        print "Fine, die then"
    else:
        go = False
While go == True:
    levelOne()
```

Right now it loops indefinitely, why is this?

Comment: `While go = True` should have raised a SyntaxError.

Comment: @unutbu that was a typo on my part, it it does not affect the infinite loop :L

Comment: @user3033697: Then fix your question.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `levelOne` isn't modifying the global variable `go`, it's creating a new *local* variable with the same name, which goes away as soon as the function returns.*

The fix is to add `global go` to the top of the function definition.

That being said, using globals is almost never the best solution. Why not just have the function, e.g., `return True` or `return False`, so you can just write `while levelOne(): pass`?

---

A few side notes while we're at it:

- It's a good idea to either (a) learn how to use the debugger, or (b) get used to adding `print` statements after each intermediate step. When trying to figure out what's going wrong, knowing where things first went wrong is a lot more helpful than trying to look at the whole big-picture view and guess where there might be a mistake.
- `str(raw_input)` is trying to call `str` on the `raw_input` function itself, meaning it will give you something like `'<built-in function raw_input>'`. You wanted to call it on the *result* of `raw_input`. Which you stored in a variable named `userInput`.
- `str` on the result of `raw_input` is useless anyway. It's guaranteed to be a string, so why try to convert it to a string?
- Just calling `str` on something, and then calling `lower` on the result, and then ignoring whatever it returns, has no effect. Neither of those functions modifies its input, they just return a *new* value, which you have to use as an argument or store in a variable if you want to get any benefit from it.
- `if go == True:` is almost never useful. If you just want to check that `go` is something truthy, just use `if go:`. If you really want to make sure that it's exactly the singleton constant `True`, as opposed to anything else truthy, use `is True`. (`1 == True`, but `1 is not True`, among other reasons.)

---

<sub>* In Python, whenever you assign to a name, that *always* creates or rebinds a local variable—unless you've explicitly told it otherwise, with a `global` (or `nonlocal`) statement, in which case it creates or rebinds a global (or non-local closure) variable instead.</sub>

Comment: Thank you, that explained a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

While there is a lot to criticise about your code, the following should work as you intended it:

```
 def levelOne():
     print "You are in a room"
     print "There is a table, on the table there is a key"
     print "There is a door to the north"
     print "Use the key to open the door and escape?"
     userInput = raw_input()
     userInput = str(userInput).lower()
     if userInput in ("y", "yes"):
         print "Ok"
     elif userInput in ("n", "no"):
         print "Fine, die then"
     else:
         return False
     return True


 while levelOne():
     pass
```

Comment: Thank you, I have been using python for roughly 15 minutes hence the derps